# Python EOF in FTP Transfer over PASV Connection

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

I'm writting a FTP Server in Python 2.7 over Sockets.
In FTP protocol, *connection has to be closed by sender to define the End Of the File* (**EOF**).

The code below is a brief example of what I am doing. Server sends file.mp4, since the server is the sender of the file, he will have to close the connection to define the end of the file.

```
C->S : PASV
S->Bind Port()
S->C : Entering Passive Mode (ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4,port1,port2)
C->Connect PASV (ip, port)
C->S : RETR file.mp4
S->C : Transfer file content via PASV connection....
S->Close PASV connection() = End Of File.
S->C : 226 File successfully transferred.
```

So far so good, but here is the error I need to handle.
If the Server has more **UPLOAD** speed than Client's **DOWNLOAD** speed (most likely).
Then the server would have already sent the file and closed connection = EOF before Client could have finished downloading it and saving it. Result, Client gets a malformatted file.
How could I figure out this?

Comment: FTP data connections use TCP. TCP is a reliable protocol and this reliability includes creation and shutdown of a TCP connection and also bandwidth management so that no data get lost.  I would suggest to take a closer look at how data transfer and close in a TCP connection work to understand why no data get lost.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know that, but in TCP there are two connections, the control/management connection and the file transfer connection. When the Transfer shuts the transfers end there, and no peer keeps reading from it, it's an standard.

Comment: You mean that the server is closing the control connection before the data connection is done? Did you actually observe this behavior? Apart from that due to the way TCP works the server might initiate a connection close of the data connection but the close is only acknowledged (and the connection closed) once the client has received all data.